# How can I flag every comment given to a post as obsolete without to flag each of them?

Tags: support, faq

A question I asked has some comments that should be deleted because they are based on one of the previous revisions of the question. How can I flag them as obsolete without to flag each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag the post for which the comments are, selecting "it needs ♦ moderator attention" as flag reason and "other"; then enter the reason for flagging, explaining the comments are obsolete.

[image: screenshot]

When flagging a post to remove its comments, preferably use one of the reasons used to flag the single comments:

- rude or offensive
- not constructive / off-topic
- obsolete
- too chatty

As you are using a custom flagging reason, you could also explain exactly why you think the flagging reason apply to the comments.

Possibly, avoid flagging the comments when the discussion is still going on, except when the comments are becoming rude, or offensive.
This method should be used when the number of the comments to the flag is the majority, or when the users involved are more than two. If the users involved in the comments are exactly two, and you are one of the users, consider deleting your own comments (except in the case they show the reason why you think they should be removed), and then flag the left comments basing on their number; if the comments still present are less than ten, consider flagging them individually.